# Initializing a hash in a controller method error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My code:

```
def edit
  @post = Post.find_by(slug: params[:id])

  options: {
    bucket:     'uploads',
    region:     'us-west-2',
    keyStart:   'uploads',
    acl:        'public-read',
    accessKey:   Rails.application.secrets.access_key_id,
    secretKey:   Rails.application.secrets.secret_access_key 
  }

  @aws_data = FroalaEditorSDK::S3.data_hash(options)
end
```

Error:

```
syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_end options: { ^
```

[Doc reference](https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/docs/sdks/ruby/file-s3-upload)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is obviously a syntax error in that article. Change

```
options: {
```

to

```
options = {
```

to assign the hash to the `options` variable.